# Using select with quosures

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

**Question**

How would I do the following using quosures?

```
library(tidyverse)
lkp <- c("am", "vs", "Sepal.Width", "Sepal.Length")
stringSelect <- function(mdat) {
   lkpOK <- intersect(lkp, names(mdat))
   mdat %>% select(one_of(lkpOK))
}
stringSelect(mtcars)
stringSelect(iris)
```

So basically, how can I subset `lkpq` below to achieve the same thing with `quos` to avoid the warning?

```
lkpq <- quos(am, vs, Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)
quosSelect <- function(mdat) {
   lkpqOK <- lkpq ##???
   mdat %>% select(!!!lkpqOK)
}
quosSelect(mtcars) ## does not work
quosSelect(iris)
```

**Context**

In my application I am mixing traditional R selectors and `tidyverse` verbs but I want to stick to one system for consistency. Most of the things are easy to translate from one "universe" to another but I am struggling with this bit.

---

*Footnote*

I know that there are plenty possibilities to solve that. But for the sake of my learning let's assume that `lkpq` is fixed and cannot be changed. So I am really interested to learn how I could use a list of quosures with `select` if some of the elements are not part of the underlying data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use

```
quosSelect <- function(mdat) {

  nm1 <- intersect(names(mdat), sapply(lkpq, quo_name))
  mdat %>% 
          select(nm1)
  }

quosSelect(mtcars) 
quosSelect(iris)
```

Comment: Ok, transfroming the quosure back to a string is of course a valid solution +1. Feels a bit hackish though. Or is my problem not meant for `quo`?

Comment: @thothal  You said the solution works with a warning.  But, I am not able to make it work.  I used `dplyr_0.7.5` and `rlang_0.2.1`  What are the versions of packages you have

Comment: Hmm, funny, starting from a fresh session, I also get an error. Now no clue, why it worked in between. I will update my post. thanks.

Comment: @thothal it may be due to some variables that you created in the earlier session.  No idea about that